# Como abrir ou fechar todos os itens de um Accordion

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

Tenho um Accordion com 3 itens e na parte superior dois botões, um onde eu queria abrir todos os itens de uma vez e outro para fechar todos os itens de uma vez, alguem sabe me dizer como fazer isso?

````
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Abrir todos</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Fechar todos</button>

<div class="container">
  <h2>teste abrir e fechar itens</h2>
  <div id="accordion">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <a class="collapsed card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo">
        Collapsible Group Item #2
      </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <a class="collapsed card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe uma forma de que os elementos apareçam na sua totalidade e também o contrário é verdadeiro, escrever esse `Javascript` obtida no próprio stackoverflow na pergunta: [Bootstrap 4 Accordion Toggle All](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830622/bootstrap-4-accordion-toggle-all) vai solucionar o seu problema, exemplo:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.btn-success').on('click', function(e) {
        $('#accordion .collapse').removeAttr("data-parent").collapse('show');
    });
    $('.btn-danger').on('click', function(e) {
        $('#accordion .collapse').attr("data-parent","#accordion").collapse('hide');
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container mt-2 mb-2">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Abrir todos</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Fechar todos</button>
  <div class="container mt-1 mb-1">
    <h2>teste abrir e fechar itens</h2>
    <div id="accordion">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
          <div class="card-body">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <a class="collapsed card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo">
        Collapsible Group Item #2
      </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
          <div class="card-body">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <a class="collapsed card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
          <div class="card-body">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

<sup>***Referencia:*** [Bootstrap 4 Accordion Toggle All Son <sup>En</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830622/bootstrap-4-accordion-toggle-all)</sup>

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente obrigado!